# Put a specific file in every Unix user's home directory when they're created and added to a particular group

Tags: files, group, useradd, user-input

How can I set up my Solaris system so that every time a user is created and assigned to a specific group, a specific file is placed in that user's home directory?

Comment: Any file in `/etc/skel` will be copied to a user's directory when the account is created. I know of no way to make this action dependent on membership of a specific group, though.

Comment: This seems a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is it that you _actually_ want to obtain? This can probably be solved with a global script that checks group membership, or similar.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by creating specific script to add new users. As Solaris offer a lot of options to `useradd` I will provide just example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# use format <script> <username> <group>
if [ "$2" = "predefined_group" ]
then useradd -k /new/path/for/skel -g "$2" "$1"
else useradd -g "$2" "$1"
fi
```

and do not forget to create new directory with skeleton files and the file you want to copy.